# Getting email from Gmail to PHP

Tags: php, email, gmail

Gmail can redirect email elsewhere. And, as far as I understand, my server can receive email.

I need that every mail that my gmail gets, should be redirected to my server. And here, PHP script should parse them and send to database.
Redirection in gmail is not problem, but what should i do next?

Is it possible at all?
If it is possible, what do I need for these, what keywords should I google?

Comment: If "Redirection in gmail is not problem" why is it even part of the question, it simply becomes "How to read mail from PHP?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an alias on your mailserver (typically in the /etc/aliases file but the location can differ) and deliver the mail to a script.

```
script    "|/usr/share/myapp/myscript.php"
```

I found [this article](http://www.evolt.org/incoming_mail_and_php) explaining it in PHP

Answer (score 1):

Try [ImapMailbox](http://code.google.com/p/php-imap) class.